# How to properly call a function from an imported file in Vue.js?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I am working on a Vue project and I need to dynamically translate select options.
The way the translations work is with a component called languageMixin that imports a translations.js file with all translations and it has a method called __(key) where key is the key of the object inside translations.js.
Here is the languageMixin:

```js
    import {translations} from "./translations.js";
    
    export const languageMixin = {
        data() {
            return {
                language: 'en',
                translations: translations,
                domain: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            __(key) {
                if (key in window.translations && window.translations[key][this.language]) {
                    return window.translations[key][this.language]
                }
                return this.translations[this.language][key];
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            const queryString = window.location.search;
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
            this.language = urlParams.get('lang');
            this.domain = urlParams.get('domain');
            if (!this.language) {
                this.language = 'en'
            }
        }
    };
```

This is a sample of the translations.js:

```js
    export const translations = {
        fr: {
            'Return reason': 'Raison du retour',
            'Product to return': 'Produits rendre',
            'Select one': 'Sélectionnez en un',
        },
        en: {
            'Return reason': 'Return reason',
            'Product to return': 'Product to return',
            'Select one': 'Select one',
        },
    }
```

The main component where the select input is:

```js
    import { Multiselect } from "../modules/multiselect/vue-multiselect.js";
    import { languageMixin } from "../mixins/languageMixin.js";
    
    
    Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);
    
    const templateReasonField = `
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label :for="'refundselectReason1'">{{ __('Return reason') }}*</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <multiselect :id="'refundselectReason1'" v-model="selectedReason" @select="reasonSelected($event)" :options="getReasons" label="label" track-by="value" placeholder="Select One" required></multiselect>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    
    export const ReasonField = {
        template: templateReasonField,
        mixins: [languageMixin],
        props: [],
        components: {
            Multiselect
        },
        data() {
            return {
                reasons: [
                    {value: 'test1', label: this.__('Return reason')},
                    {value: 'test2', label: this.__('Product to return')},
                    {value: 'test3', label: this.__('Select one')}
                ],
                otherReasonOpt: {value: 'Other', label: 'Other'},
                selectedReason: null,
                otherReason: ''
            }
        },

Translation works in the template
 {{ __('Return reason') }} 
 where actually returns the translated word, but if I try to use the translation through the languageMixin outisde the template like this this.__('Return reason') I am getting this error



    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')
        at VueComponent.__ (languageMixin.js:16:37)
Where line 16 is this:

    return this.translations[this.language][key];
```

So my guess is that I am calling the languageMixin **(key) method in the wrong way which is this.**('Return reason').

Any hint?

---

### UPDATE

As suggested by Ian Brindley I tried to add the logic of calling the options in the computed as follows:

```js
     data() {
        return {
            reasons:  this.getAllReasons()
    },
      computed: {
        getAllReasons() {
            return [
                {value: 'test1', label: this.__('Return reason')},
                {value: 'test2', label: this.__('Product to return')},
                {value: 'test3', label: this.__('Select one')}
            ]
        }
    },
  },
```

But unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to access data from the mixin in the component `data` method when the mixin data is applied after the component data. Perhaps using a computed property would work?

Comment: I tried but same error occurs. I updated the question with your solution, is that what you meant?